# how to add multiple attachment using thunderbird commandline?

Tags: thunderbird

I am stuck at this problem and not really aware of the syntax. How do I attach multiple not one?

This is for single attachment: `thunderbird -compose attachment=/home/jj/test.docx`

But I want to do something like this: 
`thunderbird -compose attachment=/home/jj/test.docx&/home/jj/test1.docx`

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By using the command

```
 thunderbird -compose "attachment='/home/jj/first.txt,/home/jj/second.txt'"
```

under Linux both files are attached. I think it should work for all operating system but I did not test it there.

Answer (score 0):

This also works in Windows:

```
thunderbird -compose "attachment='C:\first.txt,C:\second.txt'"
```